# Restricting access of an user based on a user attribute

Tags: laravel, php-7.2

I have users table. These users table has company_id attribute.

I have some generic pages with ids for ex.

https://www.test.com/customer_question/p/4701/c/40960

This url needs to be access only if the logged in user has specific company_id. Otherwise some other people can just access to link by just incrementing IDS

So that in each controller ( index,store,update etc. ) I have to check with something like this

```
$company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
$verify_seller = DB::table('sellers')
    ->select('*')
    ->where('company_id', '=', $company_id)
    ->get();

if ($verify_seller->isEmpty())
    return "This product neither belongs to your seller account nor another seller's product";
```

I think I can handle this by putting the code above to _construct function for each customer.

What is the best way to handle this kind of situation with Laravel?

Laravel version 5.6

Comment: You can use the middleware for that.https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

Comment: I don't know the reasons but whenever I hear middleware, I scare of it :)

Answer (score 2):

Two way.

1. Middleware

   ```
   class CheckSeller
   {
        public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
       {
             $company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
             $verify_seller = DB::table('sellers')
             ->select('*')
             ->where('company_id', '=', $company_id)
             ->get();
             if ($verify_seller->isEmpty()) {
                   return redirect()->route('main')->withError('Not Allowed')
             }

             return $next($request);
       }
   }
   ```

   in Kernel.php

   ```
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ....
        'check_seller' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\CheckSeller::class,
   ]
   ```

   in route

   ```
   Route::middleware(['check_seller'])->group(function () {
        //any controller that need to use the check_seller middleware
   });
   ```

   or if you need to do in each controller, you can do like this..

   ```
   class Example extends Controller {
         public function __construct()
         {
              $this->middleware('check_seller');
         }
   }
   ```

2. Base Controller

```
    class BaseController extends Controller {
          public function __construct()
          {
               $company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
               $verify_seller = DB::table('sellers')
               ->select('*')
               ->where('company_id', '=', $company_id)
               ->get();
               if ($verify_seller->isEmpty()) {
                    return redirect()->route('main')->withError('Not Allowed')
               }
          }
    }
```

in child controller

```
    class SellerController extends BaseController {
          public function __construct()
          {
               parent::__construct();
          }
    }
```

Comment: I will try and let you know. Which method is your preference? Middleware or Base Controller? I think Middleware is the way to go.

Comment: Middleware is the best practice.. Base controller usually for common method for reuse

Comment: Couldn't have answered this any better myself! But 100% use middleware :-)